# Easy to get authorization for google ads api

Tags: php, laravel, google-ads-api

I need to retrieve data regarding the historical number of searches for the indicated keywords. I need to use Google Ads API for this. I have been struggling with this for a long time. How to do it step by step? For now, I am trying to get authorization for this API. So far I have done the following steps:

1. created a project with google ads, downloaded the creditionals json file
2. i created a refresh token using the
   `~/go/bin/oauth2l fetch --credentials ~/your_credentials.json --scope cloud-platform`
3. I installed the googleads/google-ads-php package in my project.

Now I need to create a json file along the lines of this

```
{
  "client_id": "******.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "client_secret": "******",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "refresh_token": "******",
  "type": "authorized_user"
}
```

but the `~/go/bin/oauth2l` command itself does not do it. At most, I'll create one for myself manually. But again, more tokens are needed, including developerToken and loginCustomerId. I've read that you have to make some kind of request to get developerToken.
And now the question:
Is there a way to get authorization for this API more simply, or do you have to go through so many steps? Could you please describe the steps you need to do so briefly, because google documentation is not the best.